# Identity of Bernoulli polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

I am trying to prove the following identity:
$$B_n(1-x)=(-1)^nB_n(x)$$

I know that $$B_n(1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k B_n\cdot (1-x)^{n-k}$$
(I do not know how to write here exactly what I want. So I mean that $(1-x)$ in degree $(n-k)$). 
Hence
$$B_n(1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k B_n \sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{i} (-1)^ix^i$$

Hope, you understand what I mean. Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bernoulli polynomials are defined by the exponential generating function
$$ g(x,t) = \frac{t e^{tx}}{e^t-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{B_n(x) t^n}{n!} $$
Your equation $B_n(1-x) = (-1)^n B_n(x)$ comes from 
$$ g(1-x, t) = g(x,-t)$$
which is easy to verify.

Comment: It turns out easy. Thank you:)